# Angularjs two stage resolve (resolve dependencies)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I have a state where I need to resolve one item before I have the data to resolve the other:

```js
      .state('addtrip', {
        url: '/addtrip',
        templateUrl: 'views/addtrip.html',
        controller: 'AddtripCtrl',
        resolve: {
          auth : function($state, Auth){
            return Auth.$requireAuth().then(function(auth) {
              return Auth;
            }, function(error){
              $state.go('login');
            });
          },
          trips : function(rootRef,$firebaseArray){
            return $firebaseArray(rootRef).child(auth.uid).$loaded();
          }
        }
```

So first I want to get the auth object and only after I want to retrieve the trips of that specific user.

What's the best way to handle situations like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the guy above forgot to return a promise on the inner function

```js
.state('addtrip', {
        url: '/addtrip',
        templateUrl: 'views/addtrip.html',
        controller: 'AddtripCtrl',
        resolve: {
          auth :function($state, Auth,rootRef,$firebaseArray,$q){
             return Auth.$requireAuth().then(function(auth) {
               var p = new Promise (resolve, reject)
               resolve({
                 auth: auth,
                 trips:  $firebaseArray(rootRef).child(auth.uid).$loaded();
               });
           return p;
          })
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all i use the way explained on the [firebase website](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html#section-routers) and then just use currentauth and waitforauth in your trips function. You will have to change it a little bit to fit to your program but i use it myself and it works like this. (sorry for bad indentation in the code)

```
.run(["$rootScope", "$state", function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireAuth promise is rejected
        // and redirect the user back to the home page
        if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
            $state.go("login");
        }
    });
}])


  .state('addtrip', {
    url: '/addtrip',
    templateUrl: 'views/addtrip.html',
    controller: 'AddtripCtrl',
    resolve: {
      "currentAuth": ["firebaseRef", function (firebaseRef) {
                        // $requireAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
                        // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError (see above)
                        //return firebaseRef.refAuth().$requireAuth();
                        return firebaseRef.refAuth().$requireSignIn();
                    }],
                    "waitForAuth": ["firebaseRef", function (firebaseRef) {
                        // $requireAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
                        // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError (see above)
                        return firebaseRef.refAuth().$waitForSignIn();
                    }],
      trips : function(currentAuth, waitForAuth, rootRef,$firebaseArray){
        return $firebaseArray(rootRef).child(currentAuth.uid).$loaded();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Than lets try with promise nesting. It should work,

```
  .state('addtrip', {
    url: '/addtrip',
    templateUrl: 'views/addtrip.html',
    controller: 'AddtripCtrl',
    resolve: {
      auth :function($state, Auth,rootRef,$firebaseArray,$q){
          var defer = $q.defer();
          var obj = [];
           Auth.$requireAuth().then(function(auth) {
            obj.push(auth);
            var a = $firebaseArray(rootRef).child(auth.uid).$loaded();
            obj.push(a);
            defer.resolve(obj);
       });
        return defer.promise;
      }
}
```

OR,

```
 .state('addtrip', {
        url: '/addtrip',
        templateUrl: 'views/addtrip.html',
        controller: 'AddtripCtrl',
        resolve: {
          auth :function($state, Auth,rootRef,$firebaseArray,$q){
             return Auth.$requireAuth().then(function(auth) {
    return {
            auth: auth,
            trips:  $firebaseArray(rootRef).child(auth.uid).$loaded();
           };
          })
        }

}
        }
```

Comment: Its not working. He resolve only the auth but when I add the trips resolve its fail.

Comment: Updated. Better to use promise nesting.